# Why use third-party vector libraries at all?

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen

So I'm thinking of using the Eigen matrix library for a project I'm doing (2D space simulator). I just went ahead and profiled some code with Eigen::Vector2d, and with bare arrays. I noticed a 10x improvement in assigning values to elements in the array, and a 40x improvement in calculating the dot products.

Here is [my profiling](https://gist.github.com/4264844) if you want to check it out, basically it's ~4.065s against ~0.110s.

Obviously bare arrays are much more efficient at dot products and assigning stuff. So why use the Eigen library (or any other library, Eigen just seemed the fastest)? Is it stability? Complicated maths that would be hard to code by yourself efficiently?

Comment: Its your project, do as you please.

Comment: The timing for eigen seems extremely slow. What command line options are you compiling this with?

Comment: -g and I think -O2 however I'm just reading some more and apparently compiling with -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG speeds it up a fair bit EDIT: according to [this](http://home.uchicago.edu/~skrainka/pdfs/Talk.Eigen.pdf) it speeds up from 10x - 30x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real win for these libraies is the built in SIMD vectorization.

It looks like eigen doesn't enable that by default and you need to [enable it](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Vectorization) with a define / compiler switch.  (EDIT: Misread the link, it's enabled if it detects that the compiler supports it, and you need to enable the instructions on some compilers, still, may or may not be on by default on your compiler)

(Not to mention the fact that they are typically more thoroughly tested than a home rolled solution, and enable all sorts of complicated/interesting stuff that's a real bear to code by hand)

Comment: Arguably an even bigger win for these libraries is using things like expression templates to speed up expressions like `a * b + (c * d)` by removing any temporary allocations and unrolling into a single loop.

Comment: Did a quick wikipedia lookup, from what I can tell SIMD just allows parallel operations to be performed on vectors (correct me if I'm wrong). However, I'd just be using vectors in simple applications, mostly dot products. Are you thinking more of programming-related bear coding?

Comment: SIMD speeds up operations where you're performing the same operation on multiple pieces of data by doing them all in one instruction.  "vectorization", in this case, is the parallel computing sense, which has uses when doing calculations on vectors (the mathematical entities), but isn't only related to them.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(parallel_computing)

Comment: However, you are right that the overall win depends a lot on what you're actually doing, and a SIMD-enabled library is totally overkill sometimes (although you still have the it's-already-debugged benefit)

Comment: @Yuushi in fact the eigen site has a section on how Eigen matrices/classes are smart about allocating temp variables, in that it will choose whether getting rid of temps is ideal

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons to opt for standard library code.

- Better portability. An individual developer may not have considered (or may not have access to) multiple platforms.
- Better reliability. (as mentioned by Donnie) A library is usually more thoroughly tested.
- Better developer mobility. It is easier to work on other people's code if they are using standard library components.
- Avoids reinventing the wheel. You want to avoid a situation where each developer develops the same component in their own way.
- A custom implementation can get stale soon. There's only a limited amount of time upto which you would be able to keep updating and supporting your version of the library. The standard library is likely to have more support effort.
- Better "external" support. Consider the C++ STL library for instance. You will find plenty of resources from people who are not the original developers. Also, textbooks will cover standard library components, which helps new users and students to learn them without any burden to the developer.

PS/Disclaimer: My apologies, I don't know about the Eigen library. The above points are from a more general perspective regarding standard library.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look at your benchmarking and get the following result:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/eigen3/ eigen.cpp -o eigen
g++ -O3 -I/usr/include/eigen3/ eigen.cpp -o eigen_opt
g++ -I/usr/include/eigen3/ matrix.cpp -o matrix
g++ -O3 -I/usr/include/eigen3/ matrix.cpp -o matrix_opt

./eigen  3.10s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 3.112 total
./eigen_opt  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.001 total
./matrix  0.06s user 0.00s system 96% cpu 0.058 total
./matrix_opt  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.001 total
```

Eigen really is not fast unless you switch on the compiler optimizations. I also suspect that the compiler in the `-O3` case does some optimization that works against the benchmarking character. You might want to look into it.

I think this removes one of your points for not using a library: speed. Once that criteria is out of the way, there is NO reason that I could think of not to use an existing library, other than you want to do something for academic purposes, or you want to write your own library. Whenever I see a library or other code that implements its own Matrix and Vector classes these days I try to avoid it if possible. With Eigen around I even have a much lower need of Matlab...

Comment: I would be very, _very_ careful when profiling this code: The result of the dot product is never used, so the compiler might just skip calculating it altogether. By the way: One should compile all Eigen code with -DNDEBUG when profiling to disable assertions within Eigen.